# Different links in the logo depending on the selected language page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

Please tell me how can I change the link address depending on the selected language of the site? If I use Russian language, the link of Main_Page/ru if the French Main_Page/fr.

I puzzled over it for about a month and can't do it. Help me, please.

Example - https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

You can do stuff like that by modifying the nav_urls in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SkinTemplateBuildNavUrlsNav_urlsAfterPermalink

Alternatively you can edit your wikis MediaWiki:Mainpage/ru etc pages